# Deploying dbexpress Delphi application

Tags: oracle, delphi, delphi-xe3, dbexpress

I'm trying to deploy an oracle application to another machine that uses the dbxora.dll file from dbexpress. I have included the file with the program but when i run the program and try to execute a query, it returns with an error that it could not load the dbxora.dll.

I have the following all in a folder together:

```
dbxora.dll
Application.exe
dbxdrivers.ini
dbxconnection.ini
```

I have exhausted myself looking every where I possibly can think of to figure out how exactly to do this. I just can't figure it out.

As requested here are the contents of the dbxdrivers.ini file:

```
[Installed Drivers]
DBXTrace=1
DBXPool=1
DataSnap=1
ASA=1
ASE=1
DB2=1
Firebird=1
Informix=1
Interbase=1
MSSQL=1
MySQL=1
Odbc=1
Oracle=1
SQLite=1 

[DataSnap]
DriverUnit=Data.DBXDataSnap
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXClientDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxClientDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
Port=211

[ASA]
DriverUnit=Data.DBXSybaseASA
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DbxCommonDriver170.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXSybaseASAMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxSybaseASADriver170.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXSybaseASAMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxSybaseASADriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverASA
LibraryName=dbxasa.dll
LibraryNameOsx=libsqlasa.dylib
VendorLib=dbodbc*.dll
VendorLibWin64=dbodbc*.dll
VendorLibOsx=libdbodbc12.dylib
HostName=ServerName
Database=DBNAME
User_Name=user
Password=password
Port=
ConnectionString=
BlobSize=-1
ErrorResourceFile=
LocaleCode=0000
IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted

[ASA TransIsolation]
DirtyRead=0
ReadCommited=1
RepeatableRead=2

[ASE]
DriverUnit=Data.DBXSybaseASE
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DBXCommonDriver170.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXSybaseASEMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxSybaseASEDriver170.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXSybaseASEMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxSybaseASEDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverASE
LibraryName=dbxase.dll
VendorLib=libct.dll;libcs.dll
VendorLibWin64=libsybct64.dll;libsybcs64.dll
HostName=ServerName
DataBase=Database Name
User_Name=user
Password=password
BlobSize=-1
TDS Packet Size=512
Client HostName=
Client AppName=
ErrorResourceFile=
LocaleCode=0000
IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted

[ASE TransIsolation]
DirtyRead=0
ReadCommited=1
RepeatableRead=2

[DBXPool]
DelegateDriver=True
DriverName=DBXPool
DriverUnit=Data.DBXPool
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXPoolDriverLoader,DBXCommonDriver170.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXPoolDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b

[DBXTrace]
DelegateDriver=True
DriverName=DBXTrace
DriverUnit=Data.DBXTrace
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXTraceDriverLoader,DBXCommonDriver170.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXTraceDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b

[AutoCommit]
False=0
True=1

[BlockingMode]
False=0
True=1

[WaitOnLocks]
False=1
True=0

[CommitRetain]
False=0
True=1

[OS Authentication]
False=0
True=1

[Multiple Transaction]
False=0
True=1

[Trim Char]
False=0
True=1

[SQLDialect]
1=0
2=1
3=2


[DB2]
DriverUnit=Data.DBXDb2
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DBXCommonDriver170.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXDb2MetaDataCommandFactory,DbxDb2Driver170.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDb2MetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxDb2Driver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverDB2
LibraryName=dbxdb2.dll
VendorLib=db2cli.dll
VendorLibWin64=db2cli64.dll
Database=DBNAME
User_Name=user
Password=password
BlobSize=-1
ErrorResourceFile=
LocaleCode=0000
IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted
Decimal Separator=.

[DB2 TransIsolation]
DirtyRead=0
ReadCommited=1
RepeatableRead=2

[Firebird]
DriverUnit=Data.DBXFirebird
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DbxCommonDriver170.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXFirebirdMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxFirebirdDriver170.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXFirebirdMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxFirebirdDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverINTERBASE
LibraryName=dbxfb.dll
LibraryNameOsx=libsqlfb.dylib
VendorLib=fbclient.dll
VendorLibWin64=fbclient.dll
VendorLibOsx=/Library/Frameworks/Firebird.framework/Firebird
BlobSize=-1
CommitRetain=False
Database=database.fdb
ErrorResourceFile=
LocaleCode=0000
Password=masterkey
RoleName=RoleName
ServerCharSet=
SQLDialect=3
IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted
User_Name=sysdba
WaitOnLocks=True
Trim Char=False


[Informix]
DriverUnit=Data.DBXInformix
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DBXCommonDriver170.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXInformixMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxInformixDriver170.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXInformixMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxInformixDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverINFORMIX
LibraryName=dbxinf.dll
LibraryNameOsx=libsqlinf.dylib
VendorLib=isqlb09a.dll
VendorLibWin64=isqlt09a.dll
VendorLibOsx=libifcli.dylib
HostName=ServerName
DataBase=Database Name
User_Name=user
Password=password
BlobSize=-1
ErrorResourceFile=
LocaleCode=0000
IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted
Trim Char=False

[Informix TransIsolation]
DirtyRead=0
ReadCommited=1
RepeatableRead=2

[Interbase]
DriverUnit=Data.DBXInterBase
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DbxCommonDriver170.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXInterbaseMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxInterBaseDriver170.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXInterbaseMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxInterBaseDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverINTERBASE
LibraryName=dbxint.dll
LibraryNameOsx=libsqlib.dylib
VendorLib=GDS32.DLL
VendorLibWin64=ibclient64.dll
VendorLibOsx=libgds.dylib
BlobSize=-1
CommitRetain=False
Database=database.gdb
ErrorResourceFile=
LocaleCode=0000
Password=masterkey
RoleName=RoleName
ServerCharSet=
SQLDialect=3
IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted
User_Name=sysdba
WaitOnLocks=True
Trim Char=False

[IBToGo]
DriverUnit=Data.DBXInterBase
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DbxCommonDriver170.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXInterbaseMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxInterBaseDriver170.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXInterbaseMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxInterBaseDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverINTERBASE
LibraryName=dbxint.dll
LibraryNameOsx=libsqlib.dylib
VendorLib=ibtogo.dll
VendorLibWin64=ibtogo64.dll
VendorLibOsx=libibtogo.dylib
BlobSize=-1
CommitRetain=False
Database=database.gdb
ErrorResourceFile=
LocaleCode=0000
Password=masterkey
RoleName=RoleName
ServerCharSet=
SQLDialect=3
IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted
User_Name=sysdba
WaitOnLocks=True
Trim Char=False
AutoUnloadDriver=True

[Interbase TransIsolation]
ReadCommited=1
RepeatableRead=2

[MSSQL]
SchemaOverride=%.dbo
DriverUnit=Data.DBXMSSQL
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DBXCommonDriver170.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXMsSqlMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxMSSQLDriver170.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXMsSqlMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxMSSQLDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverMSSQL
LibraryName=dbxmss.dll
VendorLib=sqlncli10.dll
VendorLibWin64=sqlncli10.dll
HostName=ServerName
DataBase=Database Name
User_Name=user
Password=password
BlobSize=-1
ErrorResourceFile=
LocaleCode=0000
IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted
OS Authentication=False
Prepare SQL=False

[MSSQL9]
SchemaOverride=%.dbo
DriverUnit=DBXMSSQL
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DBXCommonDriver170.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXMsSqlMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxMSSQLDriver170.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXMsSqlMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxMSSQLDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverMSSQL
LibraryName=dbxmss9.dll
VendorLib=sqlncli.dll
VendorLibWin64=sqlncli.dll
HostName=ServerName
DataBase=Database Name
User_Name=user
Password=password
BlobSize=-1
ErrorResourceFile=
LocaleCode=0000
IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted
OS Authentication=False
Prepare SQL=False

[MSSQL TransIsolation]
DirtyRead=0
ReadCommited=1
RepeatableRead=2

[MYSQL]
DriverUnit=Data.DBXMySQL
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DbxCommonDriver170.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXMySqlMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxMySQLDriver170.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXMySqlMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxMySQLDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverMYSQL
LibraryName=dbxmys.dll
LibraryNameOsx=libsqlmys.dylib
VendorLib=LIBMYSQL.dll
VendorLibWin64=libmysql.dll
VendorLibOsx=libmysqlclient.dylib
BlobSize=-1
Database=DBNAME
ErrorResourceFile=
HostName=ServerName
LocaleCode=0000
Password=password
User_Name=user
Compressed=False
Encrypted=False

[Odbc]
DriverUnit=Data.DBXOdbc
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXOdbcDriverLoader,DBXOdbcDriver170.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXOdbcDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxOdbcDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXOdbcMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxOdbcDriver170.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXOdbcMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxOdbcDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b


[Oracle]
DriverUnit=Data.DBXOracle
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,DBXCommonDriver170.bpl
DriverAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXDynalinkDriverLoader,Borland.Data.DbxCommonDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXOracleMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxOracleDriver170.bpl
MetaDataAssemblyLoader=Borland.Data.TDBXOracleMetaDataCommandFactory,Borland.Data.DbxOracleDriver,Version=17.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=91d62ebb5b0d1b1b
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverORACLE
LibraryName=dbxora.dll
LibraryNameOsx=libsqlora.dylib
VendorLib=oci.dll
VendorLibWin64=oci.dll
VendorLibOsx=libociei.dylib
DataBase=Database Name
User_Name=user
Password=password
BlobSize=-1
ErrorResourceFile=
LocaleCode=0000
IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted
RowsetSize=20
OS Authentication=False
Multiple Transaction=False
Trim Char=False
Decimal Separator=.

[Oracle TransIsolation]
DirtyRead=0
ReadCommited=1
RepeatableRead=2

[Sqlite]
DriverUnit=Data.DbxSqlite
DriverPackageLoader=TDBXSqliteDriverLoader,DBXSqliteDriver170.bpl
MetaDataPackageLoader=TDBXSqliteMetaDataCommandFactory,DbxSqliteDriver170.bpl
```

Also here is the error message i am getting in XP

`The application or DLL \Application\Path\dbxora.dll is not a valid windows image. Please check this against your installation diskette`

Then on both Windows xp and windows 7 i get this

`Unable to load dbxora.dll (Error Code 193). It may be missing from the system path`

Comment: Please add the version of Delphi which you are using and the content of the file `dbxdrivers.ini` deployed.

Comment: I have added the dbxdrivers.ini file as requested @RRUZ

Comment: Are you tried the related documentation about this topic [Deploying dbExpress Database Applications](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Deploying_dbExpress_Database_Applications)?

Comment: I have read this but this is my first database application project and i have never worked with dll dependencies like this. I have been looking for hours on something that will point me in the right direction. @RRUZ

Comment: Can you post the exact error code and message that appears in your App?

Comment: I am not familiar with Oracle maybe OCI.DLL will be needed.

Comment: @bummi i know its not OCI.DLL because other programs use that successfully without issue. I will post the exact error code i am getting

Comment: @RRUZ i have posted the error messages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After searching for hours and finally looking up the error code, i have found this result.

I was using the 64-bit version of the dll instead of the 32-bit. After correcting this issue it works perfect.

Thanks to everyone for all their help.